# Can't get popover layout in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I've got a problem in UI automation testing of application. Uses XCTest. I can't figure out any ways to get a popover, i must check popover is appeared and all expected options are shown. You can see log of views hierarchy at the screenshot at the end of article.
Also, i've tried to get any info about this layout using accessibility inspector. There is no type, id and any other parameters. I only can get XCUIApplication().staticTexts["nameOfOptionInPopover"]. Screenshot of results:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIKPh.png)

Waiting you advices. Hope, anybody helps me. Thanks!

Comment: What classes are the popover and its buttons?

Comment: @Oletha  i have not sources of app, so classes of popover and its buttons are unknown.

Comment: I think you will need access to the app's source code to fix your problem.

Comment: @Oletha, everything was significantly simpler. I've been careless actually when had been researching XCTest available layouts to get. There is a collectionView layout and objects inside it are cells. So I got layout so: let popover = XCUIApplication().collectionViews.element(boundsBy: 0); popover.cells.element(boundsBy: numberOfCell).tap(). May be it'll be helpfull for somebody.

Comment: Yes, as of Xcode 8.0 (iOS 10), the `popovers` variable in the `XCUIElementTypeQueryProvider` protocol is always empty. However, when a popover is presented, a `PopoverDismissRegion` element does appear in the accessibility hierarchy, so it is possible to `waitForExpectations` with `XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .any).matching(identifier: "PopoverDismissRegion").element`.